# Using crates installed from Debian repositories in my Rust app

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, debian-based

I installed *librust-json-dev* with apt, but when I add *json = "0.12.0"* in my Cargo.toml and run **cargo build**, it still tries to update crates.io index and fetch json from crates.io.

Which is an official way to use the crates installed with apt in Debian-based distributions?

Comment: I don't think there is an `apt` specific thing, but there is a general vendor source replacement. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/source-replacement.html

Comment: It's also important to specify which `Cargo.toml` you'd like to use. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html